# Overriding CSS inline with css file using !important does not work

Tags: html, css, datepicker, css-selectors

I am using the [following control](https://github.com/kekeh/ngx-mydatepicker) in my angular application and the original html is what is provided. I would like to override this.

How to override inline style with css for the following class?

```
<div class="selector selectorarrow selectorarrowleft" tabindex="0" ng-reflect-klass="selector" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" ng-reflect-value="1" style="width: 252px; height: 232px; top: 33px; left: 0px;"> ...
```

Expected output: (`top` modified, `position` added)

```
<div class="selector selectorarrow selectorarrowleft" tabindex="0" ng-reflect-klass="selector" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" ng-reflect-value="1" style="width: 252px; height: 232px; top: 10px; left: 0px; position: relative">
```

Tried the following with no effect:

```
.selector.selectorarrow.selectorarrowleft[style] {
  position: relative !important
}
```

Comment: you're missing a semi-colon after !imporant

Comment: @StefanBob leaving out the last semicolon in a rule is actually ok (though not good practice)!

Comment: Also you don't need that [style] at the end of the selector. `.selector.selectorarrow.selectorarrowleft { }` should work

Comment: @StefanBob In this particular case, the attribute selector is perfectly OK. If anything, it adds specificity. See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/j7pw3cex/1/) which works the way the OP wants.

Comment: @dirtyWold what exactly do you mean by "Expected output"? Using a stylesheet does NOT add properties to an element's `style` attribute. (The changes are only visible in the browser's Inspect tool.)

Comment: @MrLister yes according to that fiddle the element is getting that position relative style. It's as you say though it won't show up in the style attribute of the html element unless you add it there with javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would erase the `[style]` and add the `div` to give it even more specifity, like:

```
div.selector.selectorarrow.selectorarrowleft {
  position: relative !important;
  top: 10px !important;
}
```